# I keep using memory more and more and don't understand why

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, heap-memory, quadtree

I'm on a project currently, that implements a quadTree, it's just a visualization of the algorithm actually, but when I run the code, I see the memory usage increasing more and more, 
now I am new to c++, but I think optimal resource management is when memory usage is constant right ?

here is how it is implemented:

```
QuadTree::QuadTree(Rectangle rec, int capacity ,const char* name ) {
this->rec = new Rectangle();
*this->rec = rec;
this->capacity = capacity;
this->nbPoints =  new int ;
*this->nbPoints = 0;
this->divided = new bool;
*this->divided = false;
this->name = name;}

QuadTree::~QuadTree() {

delete this->nbPoints;
delete this->divided;

delete this->ne;
delete this->se;
delete this->nw;
delete this->sw;

delete this->rec;}
```

here are the quadtree constructor and destructor , (you can see that i respect the "new = delete" rule for optimal resource management )

when a point is inserted , it checks on which section it belongs and if that section is subdivided , if so that check is recursively called for each subdivision and so on, as you can see :

```
class QuadTree {
private:
int* nbPoints;
Rectangle* rec;
bool* divided;
QuadTree* nw = NULL;
QuadTree* ne = NULL;
QuadTree* sw = NULL;
QuadTree* se = NULL;
const char* name;
```

each node of the quadtree has a pointer to eventual subdivisions and this memory is alocated dynamicaly i believe ( if i'm saying wrong stuff feel free to correct me please and i apologize in advance if my post does not belong in here)
anyway, i use SDL to visualize and see what is hapenning here here is the main :

```
 while (!stop) {
    Start = SDL_GetTicks();
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&e)) {
        if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
        {
            stop = true;
        }
    }

    Rectangle* rect = NULL;
    rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 700);

    QuadTree* test = NULL;
    test = new QuadTree(*rect, 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        Point P(rand() % (int)__WIDTH, rand() % (int)__HEIGHT);
        //std::cout << P.GetX() << "," << P.GetY() << std::endl;
        test->Insert(P);

    }
    test->draw(window, Renderer);
    SDL_RenderPresent(Renderer);
    cap_framerate(Start);
    delete test;
    delete rect;
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(Renderer, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    SDL_RenderClear(Renderer);
}
```

as you can see i create and destroy a quadtree each frame (this model is to implement moving points later on so i can destroy an obsolete tree and build another with updated coords) 
it works quite fine with 1000 points i run it at apriximately 35 fps so im happy with that , however i get an growig graph of memory usage :

[image]

That gets me wondering if I properly delete everything I allocate dynamically with the new pointer.

fell free to consult this git https://github.com/lucipher128/QuadTree for reproduction

Comment: If you're looking for a way to fragment your heap, search no more; you've found it. Dare I say *most* of the dynamic allocations you're performing shouldn't be.. (dynamic). Further, you left out a critical entity (the management of `Point`s within `QuadTree`).

Comment: Please show a [mre], as above i can't see any reason to use `new` and `delete` at all, just use objects rather than pointers

Comment: hey thanks for answering that fast , im sorry but i didn't get your point,how else could i make a quadtree subdivide and keep track of every node in it ?

Comment: How would we know?. It's your code. I suggest a model  that [looks like this](https://pastebin.com/gaze41ZK) is what you would be striving for, but without intimate knowledge of your application, that's the best I can offer. Dynamic allocation has a mantra: just because you 'can' doesn't mean you 'should'. It has a place, and both performance and management go out the door when you step out of that place. Your debugger (looks like VS) has some pretty nice tools to track program stats, but ultimately I suggest rethinking your dyna-strategy.

Comment: Why are all the members in your class pointers? The default should always be to store things by value.

Comment: okay so i can't use Dynamic alocation that often i see, i updated the post and added a git repos so you can see all of it easily , i wrote this code just to understand these kind of alocation and see if i could keep track of it while building a project

Comment: so my ultimate question would be " how can i get this optimal (destroy everything i create each frame ) , thank you in advance

Comment: not that you `can't` use dynamic allocations just that it probably isn't necessary in this case. If you really want to use it use smart rather than raw pointers

Comment: hi i kept trying out with unique pointers and shared pointers but when the quadtree subdivides , the nodes get deleted instantly in the subdivide function and i get a null pointer access atempt so i don't see how to implement these